# Couchbase compaction and data loss

Tags: couchbase

We had an issue with our cluster recently (running on 4.5 currently)… Compaction was not completing, it seemed to be continually running on a single node and the disk was getting close to full. We canceled the compaction and had to bounce the node to get things stable. We are using a 4 node cluster with a replication factor of 2.

What we are seeing now is some documents missing, and some documents reverted to an earlier version.

Is it possible that the scenario described above could cause documents to be missing or reverted to a previous version?

Comment: Hard to explain the reason without a full analysis,  but you probably had disk write issues.  That was causing the compaction failures and when you rebooted, the data which was still memory and hadn't been persisted yet was now missing.